# I want to change the Contents of a Label with an Entry via the Enter-Key using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a way I can use a Funtion in the Binding-Method, which takes Parameters as a Label and the Text that I want to change of the passed Label ?

```
from tkinter import *

def changeLabelName(Label, text):
    Label.configure(text=text)

def main():
    root = Tk()
    testLabel = Label(root, text="")
    testLabel.pack()
    testEntry = Entry()
    testEntry.bind('<Return>', lambda: changeLabelName(testLabel, "Hi"))
    testEntry.pack()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Did you run the code, what output did you get

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lubu1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: The function called by an event binding gets passed a parameter, whether you actually need it or not.  Define the function as `lambda evt: ...` so that it can accept this parameter.

Comment: ```testEntry.bind('<Return>', lambda l="hi",lbl=testLabel: changeLabelName(lbl,l))``` try

Comment: The Event parameter worked, Thanks !

Comment: @Sujay In your last piece of code, you will pass in the event as the second parameter and there was no point to the `lbl=testLabel`